# Http failure response for (unknown url): 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, http-status-code-404

Our monitoring tool shows us an error with the message `Http failure response for (unknown url): 400 Bad Request` with no further detailed event logs. The error occurs throughout the whole frontend application and according to logs mostly happen in production by real users on all browsers.

Could this error originate from ad blockers or browser extensions? So far, I was not successful in reproducing the error on our dev environment. What else could be the root cause of this issue?

Comment: Dont know about you, but 404 is not a 400 code... :) 400 means the data given to a request (post or get) is invalid. Where at least the base url (www.google.com) is good, the endpoint (/api/task) is good but the parameters are wrong/invalid (?param1=123). So I suggest to check your requests. Do all possible requests. Also ask your users what they did when they got the error. Or implement something that logs the any error in more detail. In some cases you have to change the error catching part to see what the request actually says is wrong.

Comment: Also dont see how this question has anything to do with javascript, angularjs or angular... You say or show nothing about these topics.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is because of CORS(cross-origin). Please check your request headers that you are passing in the header as an attribute but you did not allow on their server-side.